# commit transaction and end transaction used together

Tags: sql-server

I have come across the following T-SQL:

```
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
...
```

What is the difference between COMMIT and END transaction in this case?

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error on the "END TRANSACTION" line?

Comment: no errors as this is being called from php and any errors are being ignored, but your comment answers my question - its a coding error which has now been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`END TRANSACTION` doesn't exists in SQL Server T-SQL.

The only transaction commands available are `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, with an optional name, plus `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`, also with optional name.

`END TRANSACTION` will give you a syntax error.